# Ruby - How can I follow a .php link through a request and get the redirect link?

Tags: ruby, http, heroku

Firstly I want to make clear that I am not familiar with Ruby, at all.

I'm building a Discord Bot in Go as an exercise, the bot fetches UrbanDictionary definitions and sends them to whoever asked in Discord.

However, UD doesn't have an official API, and so I'm using [this](https://github.com/nickcharlton/urbanscraper). It's an Heroku App written in Ruby. From what I understood, it scrapes the UD page for the given search.

I want to add random to my Bot, however the API doesn't support it and I want to add it.

As I see it, it's not hard since http://www.urbandictionary.com/random.php only redirects you to a normal link of the site. This way if I can follow the link to the "normal" one, get the link and pass it on the built **scraper** it can return just as any other link.

I have no idea how to follow it and I was hoping I could get some pointers, samples or whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the "ruby" way using `net/http` and `uri`

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI('http://www.urbandictionary.com/random.php')
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

response['Location']
# => "http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=water+bong"
```

Urban Dictionary is using an HTTP redirect (`302` status code, in this case), so the "new" URL is being passed back as an http header (`Location`). To get a better idea of what the above is doing, here's a way just using curl and a system call

```
`curl -I 'http://www.urbandictionary.com/random.php'`. # Get the headers using curl -I
  split("\r\n"). # Split on line breaks
  find{|header| header =~ /^Location/}. # Get the 'Location' header
  split(' '). # Split on spaces
  last # Get the last element in the split array
```

Comment: I would argue that the "ruby" way avoids `net/http` like the plague.

Comment: I assume that there should be the same way of doing it directly in Go. That would make your project more consistent (one language) and easier to maintain.

Comment: @MarkThomas why is that?

Comment: @StephanePaquet I'm not embedding Ruby in Go, I want to extend the API so I can use it in Go. But indeed, Go follows the redirects, I didn't figured how to get the URL to which I'm redirected to and this answer provides a clue

Comment: @Elegea Because `net/http`, despite being in the std lib, is known within the Ruby community as having an outdated and cumbersome API. Common alternatives are rest-client, httpclient, HTTParty for APIs, and Mechanize for scraping.

Comment: @MarkThomas - I was trying to avoid a dependency on a gem. `net/http` is indeed cumbersome, but given that it's in the std lib and you can accomplish the task in 3 lines (or 1, if you wanted), it seems like a valid use here.

Comment: @Elegea, I understood. What I was saying is that I'm surprised that the same cannot be directly achieved in Go, because once your project will be up and running you will have to maintain coherence between 2 moving targets (your Go part and the ruby one).